# Decimal Digits in rational fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

```
Given any positive rational fraction F of 16 maximum digits beyond the decimal point
    maximum size 0.9999999999999999
    minimum size 0.0000000000000001
where 1 > F > 0 and where F is the subset of numbers that are multiples
of 0.0000000000000001...

Is there an algorithm to determine the number of significant digits (D) of the
fraction similar to the method of using log10(I) to determine the significant
decimal digits of an integer?

For example:  if F = 0.5000   then D = 1
              if F = 0.7500   then D = 2
              if F = 0.6660   then D = 3  etc. ??
```

I would like to multiply said fraction F by 10^D in order to create an integer I such that the integer I can be printed using simple binary to decimal methods as an alternative to using a table of 1600 constants, or performing 16 multiplications by 10 ( and analyzing each for the last case of significance ).

Answer (score 1):

Since each number you are considering
is of the form
$F=\dfrac{m}{10^n}$
where
$1 \le m \le 10^n-1$,
use the standard algorithm
for converting
$F$ into a continued fraction.

Then look at the convergents
and choose the first
that is a good enough approximation.

This is not optimal,
but is quite close.

Also
look up finding the
closest fraction to another fraction
withing a given tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the lowest digit and see if it is zero.  If not, you have $16$ digits.  If so, check the next to lowest and keep going up until you find a non-zero digit.

Comment: Given a number N with two parts I.F = N where I is the integer portion, F is derived by subtracting I from N, leaving F in a machine register in binary form, specifically, IEEE-754 80 bit double extended format. The data of the number itself, represented in bits, can be counted easily, i.e. 0 < bits < 53.  When multiplying this fraction by 10, the machine will round in one of four possible ways which can be controlled in advance. In any case, however, depending upon the fraction being rounded, it will leave "garbage" data on the tail end.

Comment: In other words, if i were to multiply the fraction F by 10 to the 16th power, and the fraction was actually only 5 significant figures long, the resulting data in the integer would then have various digits "inserted" on the tail end. Examining the number then usually ends up with a variable amount between 5 and 16 digits. By knowing the correct power of 10 to multiply, though, performs a truncation of the "noise" at the radix point.

Comment: Since you are told $F$ is a multiple of $10^{-16}$, there won't be noise digits inserted at the end.  If $F$ is in fact a multiple of $10^{-5}$, the faction will end with eleven zeros and if you multiply it by $10^{16}$ there will be eleven zeros to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: An integer in such a register can be massaged by log2(I)*log10(2)+1 to derive the significant decimal digits for all numbers less than 10^18  and for all numbers greater than 10^18, add 1 more. The problem, here, though, is to get F into I format. Knowing the number of bits, alone, will not resolve the number of decimal digits because for example.. the number 10 has two decimal digits, and the number 9 has 1 decimal digit, but each of those two numbers has 4 binary bits.

Comment: it would be NICE if the machine would consider it the way you describe... it actually DOES treat many numbers in the set that way. The problem is, though, because the numbers are stored in base 2 fraction format, the machine will round in various ways depending upon the number its handling. Trying to find a rounding mode that satisfies the full set has proven impossible.

Comment: This is the first you have mentioned binary, and it sounds like I have not understood the problem correctly.  I know computers usually store in binary, but the fact that you said "F is (in) the subset of numbers that are multiples
of 0.0000000000000001" indicated to me that we were talking about decimal storage.  How do you store the numbers?

Comment: One of the problems of being a "programmer" is trying to explain "impure discrete" math to people that are thinking in terms of "real math". :)  Typically, the only reason "programmers" arrive in such scenarios is because they are trying to "cheat" some particular system to get the same "discrete" results in a faster way ( which eventually, hopefully, makes it easier for real mathematicians ).

Comment: The numbers from the perspective of the machine are N, regardless of base. To multiply a number by ten, binary 10 is used, sure, but to the machine, it couldn't care less, its JABOB ( just a bunch of bits ).  The fraction in the register is well defined binary fraction, but multiplying that fraction by ten to the 16th power ( which in hexidecimal and IEEE754 format is 4341C37937E08000 ) results in the an integer scaled by 10^16, regardless of format. After it is an INTEGER though, standard "tricks" can be used to convert it to decimal ( without division which is SLOW ).

Comment: I was writing a small program to show the data to you correctly so you could see the problem of the rounding. During the course of that, i found the error in the documentation through experimenting further with the rounding modes. I have solved the need to find the answer to this problem now, however, the question is still something that if known, would speed up the overall printing algorithm umpteen fold. I was hoping the math wizards knew of some trick such as 1/radix.. or who knows, that could reveal the aprox log10(F) digit count faster than a pedantic method.

Comment: I am both a (low) amateur programmer and an (high) amateur mathematician, and have paid attention to the representation of numbers in computer memory in the past. Please define what format you have the fraction in.  I am suspecting you also have a problem with $1/7=0.14285714285714$ and want to recover $1/7$, though that violates the multiple of $10^{16}$.  The more comments you make, the less I understand what the question is.

Comment: Your statement about the numbers "if F is in fact a multiple..." made too much clear sense for the "garbage" i was seeing in the output, so THANK YOU for even considering this question.

Comment: The format is actually JABOB... its a machine register.. an x87 Floating Point Unit. It uses IEEE-754 representation for numbers in 80-bit extended double precision format. It uses this format internally only, the output ( storing from register to memory ) is in 64-bit double precision format.

Comment: very new to this web site... sorry for being a n00b. :D